# JQuery AJAX - Filter before .done()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My application has a lot of AJAX calls, each of them return a JSON response. Instead of validating the data in each of the the .done() calls, I'm trying compact the code.

**What we have so far**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        _token: token
    },
    dataFilter: function(jsonResponse) {
        return isValidJson(jsonResponse);
    }
}).done(function(jsonResponse) {
    // do things
});

isValidJson(jsonResponse) {
    try {
        var parsedJson = $.parseJSON(jsonResponse);

        if (parsedJson.error == 1) {
            notificationController.handleNotification(parsedJson.message, 'error');

            return false;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        notificationController.handleNotification('A server-side error occured. Try refreshing if the problem persists.', 'error');

        return false;
    }

    return jsonResponse; // Have to return the original data not true
}
```

The expected behavior is that if dataFilter returns false, it will trigger .fail(), if it returns true then it will continue to .done(). Instead, it just continues to .done() with the result of isValidJson().

Is there also a way to make .fail() do something standard like send a notification to the user without having to put it under every AJAX call?

Comment: No. "_A function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest. This is a pre-filtering function to sanitize the response. **You should return the sanitized data**._". So you shouldn't return TRUE of FALSE if json check is ok or not. your stratergy is wrong

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thank you for this. Do you know of a correct way to filter data outside of .done() for all AJAX calls? Should I extend something?

Comment: Have you tried this var jxhr = $.ajax(dataFilter : function() {jxhr.abort()}); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to create a shorthand for $.ajax, by extending it.

**Extending the AJAX call**

```
jQuery.extend({
    myAjax: function(params){
        // Here we can modify the parameters and override them e.g. making 'error:' do something different
        // If we want to add a default 'error:' callback
        params.error = function() {
            console.log('its failed');
        };

        // or you can specify data parse here
        if (params.success && typeof params.success == 'function') {
            var successCallback = params.success;
            var ourCallback = function(responseJson) {
                if (isValidJson(responseJson)) { // Validate the data
                    console.log('The json is valid');
                    successCallback(responseJson); // Continue to function
                } else {
                    console.log('The json is not valid');
                }
            }

            params.success = ourCallback;
        }

        return $.ajax(params);
    }
});
```

Now everytime you want to make an AJAX call in your application, you DO NOT use $.ajax({}). Instead, you use $.myAjax({});

**Example**

```
$.myAjax({
    url: 'domain.com',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
       // Do what you'd do normally, the data here is definitely JSON.
    },
    error: function(data) {}
});
```

And this special function will handle all errors same way, no need to write those validators every time.

Comment: well, there two callbacks. `error` in $.ajax and `fail` in xhr object. I was trying to set up fail of $.ajax. Edited your fiddle, now it works. https://jsfiddle.net/drnuz676/6/

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it like this (**`Not tested`**):

```
var jxhr = $.ajax({
    url: 'test',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        _token: token
    },
    dataFilter: function(jsonResponse) {        
        if (!isValidJson(jsonResponse)) {
           jxhr.abort();
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}).done(function(jsonResponse) {
    // do things
});
```

Comment: You are violating " separation of concern"  principle. Why should A's action should return false because of B's action ? A's action should return true , and later , if you want , return false for B's action.

Comment: @Kison .abort() still calls .done(). If this did work, would there be a way to automatically apply it to all future ajax requests?

Comment: @RoyiNamir  you are right, need to think on more right way how do do this

Comment: @TobyMellor, how about global ajax callback ajaxSuccess?

Answer (score 1):

By using this strategy  - you are violating "separation of concern" strategy.

Ajax should resolve or reject according to its action. Not according if response is JSON or not.

A possible solution :  ( sure there are also another solutions)

```
function GetSanitized(d) {
    return d.then(function(a) {
            if (a.indexOf('{') > -1) //check if json ( just for example)
                return $.Deferred().resolve(JSON.parse(a)); //return object
            else
                return $.Deferred().reject(a); //reject
        },

        function() {
            return $.Deferred().reject("ajax error"); //ajax failed
        }

    );
}

var ajax = $.Deferred();

GetSanitized(ajax) .then(function (a){alert(" Json p's value is "+a["p"]);},function (a){alert("Error"+a);});


ajax.resolve("{\"p\":2}"); //simulate ajax ok , valid json 
//ajax.resolve("\"p\":2}"); //simulate ajax ok , invalid json 
//ajax.reject("\"p\":2}"); //simulate ajax bad , valid json
```

http://jsbin.com/vozoqonuda/2/edit